$K^{ab}=K^{ur}M$, $M$ maximal, abelian, totally ramified
I read this property $K^{ab}=K^{ur}M$ where $M$ is a maximal totally
ramified abelian extension of $K$ (local field) as a corollary of the
following
Let $L/K$ abelian extension of a local field $K$. then there is a totally
ramified extension $L'$ abelian too, verifying
$L'^{ur}=L'K^{ur}=LK^{ur}=L^{ur}.$
Hazewinckel just said "use infinite galois theory and the fact that
$\widehat{\Bbb Z}=$Gal$(K^{ur}/K)$ is topologically free"
I don't have the least idea !
Thank for any help

If "topologicaly free" just means "Frobenius is dense" i need something open and the only open set i could imagine is a $Gal(K^{ab}/L)$ with $L/K$ finite. If $Gal(K^{ab}/L)\cap \widehat {\Bbb Z}=<F^f>$ ($F$ the Frobenius) what can i do ? And above all : How to use $M$ ???
